# How to install Pandas and Numpy in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Hi I am really really new to Python/Pycharm.

I am looking at a script written by my colleague and the first part is to 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Error Msg is :
import pandas as pd
ImportError: No module named pandas

I go to settings/Project Interpreter and see "pip". I clicked the "+" button and the error message is "Error loading package list: connect timed out"

I wonder how I can install the package.

Appreciated in advance.....

Comment: Can you not install it through the Terminal or CMD?

Comment: @kstullich I tried to install in through CMD.
I tried C:\>Python27\scripts\pip.exe install pandas.whl
erros: pandas.whl is not a valid wheel filename...

Also tried C:\> py -3.6 -m pip install pandas ... doesn't work neither

Comment: In your post, you state you tried installing it though PyCharm not your CMD

Comment: @kstullich i read a few posts and tried through CMD as well

Comment: look at @Ron answer

Answer (score 0):

you can do it without pycharm by open a terminal (linux , mac os) or cmd (windows) and running

```
pip install pandas
pip install numpy
```

Comment: @Christina you need to install `pip`. Look at the SO post, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)

Comment: @kstullich Pip comes with version 3.6. It's under C:\Python27\Scripts..

Comment: @kstullich good catch...... i notice i have two versions of Python installed... pip are installed for both versions though. How should I run it properly through CMD?

Comment: give the full path to which python version to use

Answer (score 0):

go to (CMD)
and write

pip freeze
then enter

and you can see  all library  on your laptop  and if pandas was stalling.

and if you don't see it

from terminal or (CMD) write

pip install pandas==2.7.11
then enter

or from beginning

when you create project

choose the correct  interpreter .
and create
or

from file  choose setting
then   (from bottom  in this list) choose your project's name
then   choose interpreter
then from this you can see  your library and  interpreter that you choose .
if you do not see pandas

from this try to choose another interpreter

you can see its library

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).